# how do i know if it gives pass true back

Tags: javascript, assert

Does JavaScript expression `assert("1" === 1)` gives `PASS(TRUE)` back ?

Comment: How can a question be true or false?

Comment: Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) for a list of how operators work in javascript

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1):

No, '===' means identical. "1" and 1 aren't identical because "1" is a string and 1 is a integer. Using '==' would return true.

Answer (score 0):

No it would return `false`.

The reason for this is because `===` is an equality check *without* coercion therefore the types are not converted. This means, effectively what you are comparing is a `String` to an `Number` which obviously aren't the same thing.

See [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for more info on the use of `==` vs `===`.

Answer (score -1):

String "1" is not === to integer 1, so you're evaluating assert(false) which returns `fail`.

```
("1"===1) = false
assert(false) => fail
```